# Why Vercel doesn't deploy on my domain my website?

Tags: reactjs, dns, vercel

I bought one domain in LWS and I made the connexion between them but I don't understand why VERCEL doesn't deploy the React project in this domain ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opiC5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB5c1.png)

I try to reconnect several time but doesnt work

Comment: Works fine for me, it's probably a cache. DNS servers usually take some time to redirect to the new ip

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.